# How to combine "flutter build web" output into a single html file

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

What I want to achieve is to combine all js/css into the index.html, I have achieved this with svelte as it only has a single js file. But don't know how to do it with flutter as it has many files built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter web doesn't use .css, just .js and a boot-strapping .html file.  Mixed-mode files are hard to edit, and the .js file is updated for every build, so it'd be bad to overwrite the index.html if it had localizations, like other JS packages or font references or Google Analytics.

Comment: thanks, but I think it's an ok question why downvote.

Comment: You'll have to ask the person who did that.  I didn't downvote.